# Beginner/Newb here. Need a script to apply static data

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a script where when data is selected from a drop-down, then return information from a different cell but have that data be static and not change.

1. My drop-down selects a date from a list of dates (01-01-2018)
2. The formulas on the sheet then create the answer in cell b2
3. I want the data from b2 to be applied to c2, but stay there and not be removed when a different date is chosen. That way if the data in the formulas is updated, when the same date is selected again the cell (c3) would just update.
4. Then when the next date in the order is selected (01-02-2018) I want that data from b2 to be added to c3

and so on.

Sorry if this is confusing. I a, very new to scripting.

I don't know where to even start.

I don't have any code

Answer (score 0):

## Once C2 is set it stays set until you clear it

I assumed that your drop down is in A2.

My sheet looks like this:

[image]

I just used integers 1 - 9 instead of dates because I don't know what your algorithm is anyway.  The logic should be the same or at the very least close.

This is the Data Validation for A2:

[image]

This is the onEdit() simple trigger script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var rg=e.range;
  var sh=rg.getSheet();
  var name=sh.getName();
  if(name!='Sheet57'){return;}
  if(rg.columnStart==1 && rg.rowStart==2 && e.value && e.value.length>0){
    var valueC2=sh.getRange('C2').getValue();
    var valueB2=sh.getRange('B2').getValue();
    //e.source.toast(Utilities.formatString('valueC2: %s<br />valueB2: %s<br />e.value: %s', valueC2,valueB2,e.value));
    if(!valueC2){
      sh.getRange('C2').setValue(valueB2);
    }
  }
}
```